# Настройка прав доступа к Firebase

Tags: firebase, права-доступа

Пытаясь настроить права доступа к БД Firebase конкретно под мой случай, я уже излазил доки и так и не сумел сделать все верно. Возможно тут помогут )
сейчас права выглядят дефолтно

```
{
  "rules": {
                ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
      }
}
```

структура проекта максимально простая
есть три категории

contacts - контакты привязаны к id папки
folders - папки с контактами - привязаны к id юзера
userData - данные юзера

Доступ к папкам только для авторизованных
Авторизация тоже через firebase

Вопрос - как конкретно должна выгдядеть моя настройка
Заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если только для авторизированных то должно быть  так

```
    {
      "rules":{ 
               ".read": "auth != null", 
               ".write": "auth != null ", 
              }
    }
```